# Drag effect disappears when Textfield is focused in ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield, flutter-reorderable-listview

I want to list the options of a survey using reorderablelistview, but if the focus is on one of these options, it gives the following error while dragging:

**Another exception was thrown: LeaderLayer anchor must come before FollowerLayer in paint order, but the reverse was true.**

Even when focused, I want to drag and drop without losing the focused option.

MyCode

```
 ReorderableListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          onReorder: createPollModelView.onReorder,
          children: [
            ReordarebleTextField(
              key: const Key("1"),
              text: "text1",
              onTap: () {},
              onChanged: (va) {},
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
            ),
            ReordarebleTextField(
              key: const Key("2"),
              text: "text2",
              onTap: () {},
              onChanged: (va) {},
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
            ),
            ReordarebleTextField(
              key: const Key("3"),
              text: "text3",
              onTap: () {},
              onChanged: (va) {},
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
            ),
          ],)
```